# Possible to use IIS + httpplatformhandler + django?

Tags: django, iis, httpplatformhandler

I'm implementing a django and will deploy to Azure, as the wfastcgi got errors several times before, so I changed it to httpplatformhandler, unfortunately, as I reviewed the log, I always get server error 500 while running, but I really cannot catch the errors where it came from, so, could someone give a big favor to teach me how I can debug line by line within this environment? Or any suggestions on settings that I can simulate the platform locally by using IIS + httpplatformhsndler + django? Or how can I capture errors under httpplatformhandler?

I'm using python 3.5.x, django 1.10.x, httpplatformhandler + azure web app, I don't have VM or on-premises network, just deploy to azure web app directly.

Very Thankful if someone can let me know how you do so.

Thanks a lot at all!

Answer (score -1):

Refer to: [django with httpplatformhandler](https://prmadi.com/django-app-with-httpplatformhandler-in-azure-app-services-windows/).
The key is to start WSGI server using [Waitress](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/). The dataflow is `web client <-> IIS <-> WSGI <-> Django`

Comment: This is not an answer, it's just a link to a paywall